# How can I flush the jtl file to disk?

Tags: jmeter

Logging results to a jtl file and at the end of the test plan I would like to save the jtl file to a database with a "put" statement via jdbc.
However when I do that it looks like the jtl file is not fully written to disk yet? Is there anyway I can force Jmeter to write the jtl file to disk before I do my jdbc request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special property which controls this:  `jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush` and it defaults to `false`

So if you run JMeter as:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true -n -t test.jmx .....
```

it will write the sample results to the .jtl file as soon as they will be available.

If you want to make this change permanent - add the next line to *user.properties* file.

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)